# Get CDF from PDF

Tags: density-function, cumulative-distribution-function

I am trying to evaluate the integral of pdf to get CDF but because of the absolute value, everytime I fail.
can someone help me out ? thanks
please note this is not HW, it is not practice problem where I am stuck solving it.

[image]

Comment: Why not draw a graph of the PDF so you can *see* the area you are trying to compute?  If you have poor vision, you might prefer an algebraic approach, in which case you should ponder the relationship between $|x|^2$ and $x^2$.

Comment: if I split it up to two parts, will the limit point be from -1 to 0 and 0 to x?

Comment: You might want to think about your limits of integration vs the dummy variable in your integral. Also, can you articulate why you want to split this integral into two parts?

Comment: because of the absolute value ! now I am thinking if just get rid of absolute value and evaluate the integral  ? if I do that, that would be very easy

Comment: will the limit point be from -1 to x , and the pdf is 3/2(x^2)  ?

Comment: damn I plotted both abs(x)^2 and x^2 , and they are the same thing !

Comment: That is what whuber was getting at with his suggestion to think about their differences :) Does that fix your problem?

Comment: You might consider writing up your findings as an answer so that you can accrue additional reputation.